# Return Array from foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function get_inner_refs($referral){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE binery_referral='$referral'");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $referral = $row['username'];

                $referrals[] =  $row['username'];
                $this->get_inner_refs($referral, $referrals);
            }

        }   
        return $referrals;
    }
```

here i want to return an array of all users but it returns only first value from database,

Comment: It seems that you're not passing the correct parameters to the recursive function. For starters, the signature only has one, but you pass two. From a quick look you should be passing the array, like this `$this->get_inner_refs($referrals);`. As a side note, this looks *terrible* for your database.

Comment: Shouldn't you assign get_inner_refs to a variable in the loop? Its just running and not doing anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a `private` variable to assign to and create a get method:

```
private $referrals;

public function get_inner_refs($referral)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE binery_referral='$referral'");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $username = $row['username'];
                $this->referrals[] = $username;
                $this->get_inner_refs($username);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

public function getReferrals()
{
    return $this->referrals;
}
```

Then to use:

```
$referrals = $ReferralClass->get_inner_refs($username)->getReferrals();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can edit like this

```
public function get_inner_refs($referral='',$referrals = []){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE binery_referral='$referral'");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $referral = $row['username'];

                $referrals[] =  $row['username'];
                $this->get_inner_refs($referral, $referrals);
            }

        }   
        return $referrals;
    }
```